# Loop being overwritten, beginner Java

Tags: java

Something wrong with this loop (I think). When the loop executes, it clears the data that is saved in the variable userHandValue. I've tried different loops to work around it, but I think everything is fine except the new card drawn isn't being added to the hand. When you run the program, you'll see what I'm talking about. You can start off with a hand that totals up to 13, then when you hit, your hand can total something like 10. I just think its not concatenating the way it's supposed to.

Please keep in mind that I am new at this, so if the formatting is too messy for your tastes, instead of closing my post, please offer suggestions (helping with the actual problem would be great, too).  Thank you.

```
do {
 if (userHandValue < 21) {
     System.out.println("Would you like to hit? (Y/N)");
     hit = dataIn.readLine();
     hit = hit.toUpperCase();
 }
 again = hit.compareTo("Y") == 0;
 if (again) {
     // users next card draw
     randomGenNum = (int)((range * Math.random()) + 1)*2;
     // assigning the user hand value & card, pulling index from array
     tempUserHandValue = arrayCardValues[randomGenNum];
     // Check if the user was dealt an ace
     if ((tempUserHandValue != 11) && (randomGenNum >= 2) && (randomGenNum <= 5)) {
         tempUserHandValue = userHandValue + 10;
     }
     userCard = arrayCardSuites[randomGenNum];
     // displaying values to the screen
     System.out.println("Your next card is " + userCard);
     // adding new card to total hand value and displaying to user
     userHandValue = userHandValue + tempUserHandValue;
     System.out.println("Your new total hand value is: " + (userHandValue));
}
} while (again);
```

Here is everything:

```
/*
 *This is a simple BlackJack game written by C. Auito and D. Harrington for CS241. 
 *Code snippets were taken from the following open source files:
 * http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/75554-blackjack-game/
 * update test
 * 
 */
package blackjackclassproject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

/**
 * @author C. Auito <chris.auito@gmail.com>
 */
public class BlackJackClassProject {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader dataIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        //Declare Variables
        boolean again = true;
        //int again = 0;
        do {
            double range = 26;
            int randomGenNum;
            int kitty = 1000;
            int yourBet;
            int userHandValue = 0;
            int userDrawnValue;
            int dealerHandValue = 0;
            int dealerDrawnValue;
            String playAgain;
            String hit = "";
            String strBetAmount;
            String userCard, dealerCard;
            int[] arrayCardValues = {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6,
                7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10};
            String[] arrayCardSuites = {
                "", "", "Ace/Clubs", "Ace/Diamonds", "Ace/Hearts", "Ace/Spades",
                "2/Clubs", "2/Diamonds", "2/Hearts", "2/Spades", "3/Clubs", "3/Diamonds", "3/Hearts", "3/Spades",
                "4/Clubs", "4/Diamonds", "4/Hearts", "4/Spades", "5/Clubs", "5/Diamonds", "5/Hearts", "5/Spades",
                "6/Clubs", "6/Diamonds", "6/Hearts", "6/Spades", "7/Clubs", "7/Diamonds", "7/Hearts", "7/Spades",
                "8/Clubs", "8/Diamonds", "8/Hearts", "8/Spades", "9/Clubs", "9/Diamonds", "9/Hearts", "9/Spades",
                "10/Clubs", "10/Diamonds", "10/Hearts", "10/Spades", "Jack/Clubs", "Jack/Diamonds", "Jack/Hearts",
                "Jack/Spades", "Queen/Clubs", "Queen/Diamonds", "Queen/Hearts", "Queen/Spades", "King/Clubs",
                "King/Diamonds", "King/Hearts", "King/Spades"
            };
            //get bet amount from user
            System.out.println("How much do you want to bet?");
            strBetAmount = dataIn.readLine();
            yourBet = Integer.parseInt(strBetAmount);
            //draw three cards (one card face up for dealer, two for player)
            //dealer first drawn card
            randomGenNum = (int) ((range * Math.random()) + 1) * 2;
            //assigning the dealer hand value & card, pulling index from array
            dealerHandValue = arrayCardValues[randomGenNum];
            //Check if the dealer was just dealt an ace
            if ((randomGenNum >= 2) && (randomGenNum <= 5)) {
                dealerHandValue = dealerHandValue + 10;
            }
            int tempDealerHandValue = dealerHandValue;
            dealerCard = arrayCardSuites[randomGenNum];
            //displaying values to the screen
            System.out.println("The dealer is showing a " + dealerCard);
            //dealers second drawn card
            randomGenNum = (int) ((range * Math.random()) + 1) * 2;
            //assigning the dealer hand value & card, pulling index from array
            dealerHandValue = arrayCardValues[randomGenNum];
            //Check if the dealer got an ace
            if ((dealerHandValue != 11) && (randomGenNum >= 2) && (randomGenNum <= 5)) {
                dealerHandValue = dealerHandValue + 10;
            }
            dealerCard = arrayCardSuites[randomGenNum];
            //users first drawn card
            randomGenNum = (int) ((range * Math.random()) + 1) * 2;
            //assigning the user hand value & card, pulling index from array
            userHandValue = arrayCardValues[randomGenNum];
            //Check if the user was just dealt an ace
            if ((randomGenNum >= 2) && (randomGenNum <= 5)) {
                userHandValue = userHandValue + 10;
            }
            int tempUserHandValue = userHandValue;
            userCard = arrayCardSuites[randomGenNum];
            //displaying values to the screen
            System.out.println("Your first card is " + userCard);
            //users second drawn card
            randomGenNum = (int) ((range * Math.random()) + 1) * 2;
            //assigning the user hand value & card, pulling index from array
            userHandValue = arrayCardValues[randomGenNum];
            //Check if the user got an ace
            if ((userHandValue != 11) && (randomGenNum >= 2) && (randomGenNum <= 5)) {
                userHandValue = userHandValue + 10;
            }
            userCard = arrayCardSuites[randomGenNum];
            //displaying values to the screen
            System.out.println("Your second card is " + userCard);
            System.out.println("Your total hand value is: " + (tempUserHandValue + userHandValue));
            //check for the either player having a blackjack(hand value = 21)
            if ((dealerHandValue == 21) && (userHandValue != 21)) {
                //dealer = 21 user != 21 dealer wins, kitty - bet, game over 
            }
            if ((dealerHandValue != 21) && (userHandValue == 21)) {
                //user = 21 dealer != user wins, kitty + bet, game over
            }
            if ((dealerHandValue == 21) && (userHandValue == 21)) {
                //dealer and user = 21 noone wins, users kitty is not changed, game over
            }
            //if neither player has 21 continue through the loop
//start the users loop
            //while(userHandValue < 21)
            if (userHandValue < 21) {
                System.out.println("Would you like to hit? (Y/N)");
                hit = dataIn.readLine();
                hit = hit.toUpperCase();
            }
            if (hit.compareTo("Y") == 0) {
                again = true;
            } else {
                again = false;
            }
            if ((again) == (true)) {
                //users next card draw
                randomGenNum = (int) ((range * Math.random()) + 1) * 2;
                //assigning the user hand value & card, pulling index from array
                tempUserHandValue = arrayCardValues[randomGenNum];
                //Check if the user was dealt an ace
                if ((tempUserHandValue != 11) && (randomGenNum >= 2) && (randomGenNum <= 5)) {
                    tempUserHandValue = userHandValue + 10;
                }
                userCard = arrayCardSuites[randomGenNum];
                //displaying values to the screen

                System.out.println("Your next card is " + userCard);
                //adding new card to total hand value and displaying to user
                userHandValue = userHandValue + tempUserHandValue;
                System.out.println("Your new total hand value is: " + (userHandValue));
            }
        } while (again == true);
```

Comment: What do you see when you step through your code in your debugger?

Comment: Note that `while (again == true);` this is an infinite loop if again is true.

Comment: I need the while (again == true); to draw another card if the player wants to hit.. i think.  it will continue to hit as long as the player enters "Y" or reaches 21.  Somehow, when a card is drawn, the value overwrites the total of what is already in their hand.

Comment: Comparing `boolean` values with contants `true` or `false` does not make any sense. You should simply write `if(again)` and `while(again)`. This also applies to constructs such as `if(something) again = true else again = false`, it should be written as `again = something`.

Comment: @assylias I think there is a `do {` missing from the beginning of the code...

Comment: @peter The debugger doesn't show any errors, but I have never tried using one until just now.

Comment: @saberMule Are you saying that every line of code does exactly what you expect or that you don't get an Error on the console?

Comment: This is not enough code to really help you. However, I have the feeling that the type of `range` is an int instead of a double or float. This will evaluate `(range * Math.random())` to 0 or `range`

Comment: The debugger is not there to show you errors. It enables you to execute the program line by line and see what happens. And you can just go to the next line whenever you are ready. This way you will see, how your loop works.

Comment: @ppeterka There is a do { missing from the beginning of the method, but i didn't copy the entire thing.  My last post (incidentally, my first on here) was closed because partially because I had too much code unrelated to the problem.  Could someone tell me how to highlight the code inline in a reply?

Comment: @Jagger Thanks, I'll do that as well.

Comment: @saberMule Could you put some more code? For example I do not see any place with the `userHandValue` definition and initialization.

Comment: I'll add everything I've got.  I think I may have more issues to work out with it than I thought.

Comment: **note: It is all one method, and probably formatted incorrectly.  This is my first language class, and I am only a month in to it.  My apologies if it is difficult to read.

Comment: From the comments in code. It looks like you have copied the blackjack program from net and trying to make it work but dint know what to do as you dint write it.

Comment: @MukulGoel I stated that right in the comments, mukul.  I put the link there, feel free to see the original code and compare.  As you will see, I've managed to get it working somewhat better than it did originally.  Are you willing to offer any suggestions, or just speculation?

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring several variables inside the loop (including `userHandValue`) which means there is going the be a new instance created for them in every iteration.

All variables that need to carry their state between iterations should be declared outside of the loop or they should be declared as class attributes.